# Reactのinputタグで一文字ずつ確定され「テスト」が「tえst」と入力される

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Reactで下記のようなinputを作成し、入力値をオブジェクトの状態変数で管理しています。
ただ、inputタグに「テスト」と入力すると「tえst」と入力され、一文字入力するたびに確定されるためカタカナや漢字への変換ができません。

何か考えられる原因等ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけたら幸いです。

コード

```
const [userParams, setUserParams] =
useState<{id: number, name: string, email: string}>({id: 0, name: "", email: ""});


        <input
          type="text"
          value={userParams.name}
          onChange={(event) => {
            props.setUserParams({
              ...userParams,
              name: event.target.value,
            });
          }}
        ></input>
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[React で入力フォームの onChange イベントを IME ON のときに無視する](https://maku.blog/p/cv6fpx7/)